# concavity of $\ln(1+x^2)$

Tags: calculus

I was asked where the graph of $\ln(1+x^2)$ is concave up. Doing the second derivative test I found it is only concave up on the interval $(-1,1)$. However, looking at the graph it seems to be concave up for all real numbers. How can this be? 
[image]

Comment: The graph definitely doesn't look concave up around, say, $x=5$ to me ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concave up means the graph is above its tangent lines. Mentally drawing a tangent line at $x=5$ on the graph you posted, it seems to me that the tangent line is above the graph, and so the graph is concave down. Your result you calculated from the second derivative test seems to reasonably match the graph to me.

Comment: or *concave up = derivative increasing*